# Putting content in a Div ID with javascript

Tags: javascript

this is what I have and it doesn't work for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("testzak").innerHTML = "whatever";
</script>

<div id="testzak"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("testzak").innerHTML = "whatever";
};
```

The reason why it does not work, is because the [DOM tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) is not yet built when you run your code, therefore, it can't find the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/t4A73/

Comment: Onload might take a while to fire, as you'll have to wait for iframes, images, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, by the time your code was executed, the `<div>` wasn't parsed yet by the browser; you would have gotten an error because `getElementById()` returned `null`.

Quick solution, just put the script after the div:

```
<div id="testzak"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("testzak").innerHTML = "whatever";
</script>
```

Typically you would put the script at the bottom of your page, just before the closing body tag, but this should work fine as well.

Btw, this is actually faster than waiting for `window.onload` or DOMReady.

Comment: you're right. This worked a lot quicker than window.onload. Thanks! :)